# Apache - where is default HTML coming from

Tags: apache

Setup Apache webserver to browser a directory from a remote machine. Looking to change the HTML a bit, but cannot find where it's coming from

Does anyone know where this HTML is coming from?

[image: Apache - default directory browsing HTML]

Searched in all the drive, but couldn't locate this HTML file. Any ideas anyone? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being generated directly by the apache module called mod_autoindex.

There is no easy way to directly modify the html, but you can configure the html output, by configuring mod_autoindex.

See documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: I see, was hoping it's an easy fix. Sigh, will just leave it like that. Thank you!